# I am getting rank = 0 while working on a query with relevance ordering

Tags: mysql

I am working on a search algorithm and I am having trouble while trying to rank them by relevance. Can anyone gently provide some help ? 
$This is the query:

```
SELECT `listings`.*, 
       `c`.`category_name`, 
       `p`.`profile_name`, 
       CASE WHEN Lower(listings.title) IN ("pizzeria", "ristorante") THEN 1 ELSE 
       0 end 
       + CASE WHEN Lower(listings.address) IN ("pizzeria", "ristorante") THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
       end + CASE WHEN Lower(c.category_name) IN ("pizzeria", "ristorante") THEN 
       1 ELSE 
       0 end + CASE WHEN Lower(co.province) IN ("pizzeria", "ristorante") THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
       end             AS rank, 
       `co`.`comune`   AS `comune`, 
       `co`.`province` AS `province`, 
       `co`.`region`   AS `region`, 
       `co`.`short_code`, 
       `u`.`username` 
FROM   `listings` 
       LEFT JOIN `comune` `co` 
              ON `listings`.`id_city` = `co`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `aauth_users` `u` 
              ON `listings`.`id_user` = `u`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `categories` `c` 
              ON `listings`.`id_category` = `c`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `profiles` `p` 
              ON `listings`.`id_profile` = `p`.`id` 
WHERE  ( `listings`.`title` LIKE '%pizzeria%' escape '!' 
          OR `c`.`category_name` LIKE '%pizzeria%' escape '!' 
          OR `listings`.`address` LIKE '%pizzeria%' escape '!' 
          OR `co`.`province` LIKE '%pizzeria%' escape '!' ) 
        OR ( `listings`.`title` LIKE '%ristorante%' escape '!' 
              OR `c`.`category_name` LIKE '%ristorante%' escape '!' 
              OR `listings`.`address` LIKE '%ristorante%' escape '!' 
              OR `co`.`province` LIKE '%ristorante%' escape '!' ) 
ORDER  BY `rank` ASC 
LIMIT  15
```

Having the text pizzeria in listings.title and ristorante in category name should output [rank] => 2 but it shows [rank] => 0  when i print the result array.

Comment: Are you really using a case sensitive collation?

Comment: @Strawberry I am not sure...

Comment: If `SELECT 'hello' = 'HELLO'` returns 0, then you are. Otherwise not.

Comment: @Strawberry the problem might be because the title contains the text "pizzeria" but is not equal to it . I think I must use LIKE operator but I dont know how...

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)